# Using static html/css/jquery landing pages in ReactJS project

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css, reactjs

so I had an idea of generating various "landing pages" for my project that would use similar elements with different data.

The idea is to essentially to have my react app (create-react-app) load a "container component" and would then display static landing pages.

For example files are...

`screenContainer.jsx`

`pageOne.html`
`pageTwo.html`

Depending on the user's choice I can render `pageOne.html` or `page2.html`. These pages are "templates" which work with jquery css, etc.

Is this possible? If so, what is the best approach.

I'm using `html-loader` now but am stuck at this:

```
./src/landingPages/serre/assets/js/plugins/jquery/jquery-3.3.1.min.js
  Line 2:1:      Expected an assignment or function call and instead saw an expression  no-unused-expressions
```

Any ideas?

Thanks!

Here is my current file react screen container component:

```
require("es6-object-assign/auto");
import React, { Component, Fragment } from "react";
import $ from "jquery";

import Page from "../landingPages/serre/index.html";
var ReactDOMServer = require("react-dom/server");

var HtmlToReactParser = require("html-to-react").Parser;

var htmlDoc = { __html: Page };

class CreatorLandingPageContainer extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
  }

  render() {
    return <Fragment>HELLO{this.renderPage()}</Fragment>;
  }

  renderPage() {
    var htmlToReactParser = new HtmlToReactParser();
    var reactElement = htmlToReactParser.parse(htmlDoc);
    return reactElement;
  }
}

export default CreatorLandingPageContainer;
```